# Gnuplot : How to 2D plot a 3D data file, using certain lives

Tags: plot, 3d, 2d, gnuplot

So, this question has been answered before but it didn't actually worked for me.

Let's say we wave 4 blocks with 4 columns and 3 lines.

I want to plot the 3rd line of every block, picking two columns of my choice.

The command

plot "data.0000.tab" every ::2::2 using 1:3 with lines

did not work.(Empty plot)

Any advice? :(

Comment: Do the points show up when you plot `with points` (or `with linespoints`) instead? gnuplot draws lines only between points it considers "adjacent", which points from different blocks usually are not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you intended to type

plot "data.0000.tab" every :::2::2 using 1:3 with lines

Comment: Just fixed it (also removed one ':' )